# Set Array length to value passed to Constructor

Tags: java, arrays, variables, constructor

I'm trying to create something like this...

```
Class WordStore {

    private int size;
    private String words[];

    public WordStore(int n) {
        size=n;
        words[]=new String[size];
    }

    ...
}
```

So I can have words as a global variable, being able to access it from any method in the class, without having to pass it through as an argument. The length of the array words has to be the int value passed to the constructor, which is passed from another class.
It has to be an array, not ArrayList or any other list.

However at present it does not compile, what corrections do I need to make to allow this to compile.

Comment: So whats your question ?

Comment: Do you have any questions ?

Comment: did you try the code you posted? If yes did it throw any errors? If yes which?

Comment: Get rid of the `[]` in the assignment, but then it should be fine.

Comment: No need to store size separately though, it's always available as words.length

Comment: I understand your premise, but ... what exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you need from us? What's wrong?

Comment: `The length of the array words has to be the int value passed to the constructor`: then do this: `words = new String[n]`;

Comment: I dont know what you want, but i think you want to make String words[] public? normaly access member variables over methods..

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: It wasn't compiling before, but because of feedback I have got it to work, so thanks to everyone that responded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient

```
private int size;

private String words[];

public WordStore(int n){
     words =new String[n];
}
```

If you don't need the size to be global

Answer (score 3):

`words[]=new String[size];` should be like this  `words=new String[n];`

Comment: @Prabhakaran Possibly (and the downvote isn't from me) they want some explanation as to why the line could be changed. Although I can't think of any explanation other than "because thats the way java is written.

Comment: @user3074612 This confusion is probably caused in large part because of how you declared `private String words[];`, the [] is part of the type, so it's more usual to write `private String[] words;`, once you do that it's obvious that the [] isn't part of the name

Answer (score 1):

As other answerers have stated you should replace

`words[]=new String[size];` with `words=new String[n];`

This is because the [] is part of the variables **type** not it's name. This confusion is understandable because when declaring a variable it is optional whether to put the [] with the rest of the type or the name. For this reason it is usual to declare a variable of an array type as

```
private String[] words; //type: String[] name: words
```

rather than the non standard

```
private String words[]; //still type: String[] name: words, but less clear
```

Once you do this everything becomes much more consistent, you wouldn't repeat the String type when using the variable so you don't repeat the [] either.

Additionally Class should be class, as keywords are lower case in java